# Javascript and Jquery - IE blocking it running (Galleria)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, galleria

I have linked to the Jquery library at google in my header, and my local copy of the Galleria Javascript file - as the instructions on the Galleria website said to do.

The code functions perfectly in Chrome. However, when attempting to view the site in IE9 I am faced with "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls." This is preventing (without user input) the Javascript/Jquery/Galleria stuff to function; it is also prevented an embedded Youtube video from displaying.

What am I missing - plenty of other websites use these functions and I don't get IE giving this message. What do I need to add or change?

I am viewing the website from my PC - it is stored locally at the moment. 
Cheers!

Comment: make sure you are not linking https scripts on http page

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are running your website locally. You can be sure that this will not happen once you upload it to a webserver.

You can also run a local webserver. I can recommend WAMP:

http://www.wampserver.com/en/